# MongoDB: query by @DBRef

Tags: mongodb, dbref

I have a class hierarchy designed for store user notifications:

```
@Document
public class Notification<T> {
   @Id
   private String id;
   @DBRef
   private T tag;
   ...
}

@Document
public class NotificationA extends Notification<WrappedA> {
}

@Document
public class NotificationB extends Notification<WrappedB> {
}

    ...
```

This is useful for returning polymorphic arrays, allowing me to store any kind of data in the "tag" field. The problem starts when the wrapped objects contains @DBRef fields:

```
@Document
public class WrappedA {
   @Id
   private String id;
   @DBRef
   private JetAnotherClass referenced;
   ...
}
```

Queries on the fields of "tag" works fine:

```
db.NotificationA.find( {"tag.$id": ObjectId("507b9902...32a")} )
```

But I need to query on the fields of JetAnotherClass (two levels of @DBRef fields). I've tried with dot notation and also with subobjects but it returns null:

Dot notation:

```
db.NotificationA.findOne( {"tag.$referenced.$id": ObjectId("508a7701...29f")} )
```

Subobjects:

```
db.NotificationA.findOne( {"tag.$referenced": { "_id": ObjectId("508a7701...29f") }} )
```

Any help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you look like you are only querying by `_id` I believe you can do:

```
db.NotificationA.findOne({"tag.$id": ObjectId("blah")});
```

However:

> But I need to query on the fields of JetAnotherClass (two levels of @DBRef fields).

DBRefs are not JOINs, they are merely a self describing `_id` in the event that you do not know the linking collection it will create a helper object so you don't have to code this yourself on the client side.

You can find more on DBRefs here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/

Basically you can query the sub fields within the DBRef from the same document, i.e.: `DBRef.$_id` but you cannot, server-side, resolve that DBRef and query on the resulting fields.

Comment: Ok, it seems I've made a conceptual error. Is there a way to solve this from Java client?

Comment: @Roi The only way is to resolve the JOINs client side manually, it is pretty standard across all platforms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067197/mongodb-and-joins

Comment: Starting on Mongo 3.2 you can use `$lookup`, more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39476690/1195507