# Spring Data MongoDB: how to implement "entity relationships"?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

The title of this question is quite contradictory since I'm trying to implement relations in a non-relational database... :)

But what I mean is how to **define associations between entities** in application model classes working with MongoDB.

Working with JPA I often use `@ManyToMany` or `@OneToMany` annotations to define relationships between objects. Is there something similar in Spring Data MongoDB?

Studying MongoDB I realized that there are two possible approaches to the association: **References** and **Embedded Data**.

Which one is used by Spring Data? Is it possible to configure the association mode?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the @DBRef annotation to persist the referenced class in a separate collection, else the document will be persisted in the same document (json).
The use of DBRef require an extra query for the mongodb driver, you should consider this to analyze performance issues.

From [spring data documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html)

*@DBRef - applied at the field to indicate it is to be stored using a com.mongodb.DBRef.*

*7.3.4 Using DBRefs
The mapping framework doesn't have to store child objects embedded within the document. You can also store them separately and use a DBRef to refer to that document. When the object is loaded from MongoDB, those references will be eagerly resolved and you will get back a mapped object that looks the same as if it had been stored embedded within your master document.*

Comment: Be careful with @DBRef. You won't be able to use projections for referenced documents. I.e. `docA = {id:1, anotherDoc:DBRef(id:2)}` and `docB = {id:2, foo:bar}`. Now you can use a projection when querying for `docA`, but I won't apply to `docB`. What I mean is, you **can't** do something like this projection `{anotherDoc.foo:0}`. It will always fetch the whole `docB`.

Comment: @BenjaminM since Mongo 3.4.4 you actually [can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45997377/1377895) use aggregations to "left-join" referenced tables via ObjectID lookups and use further projections to filter out unwanted stuff. However, it isn't that convenient to use

Answer (score 2):

You can use [RelMongo](https://kaiso.github.io/relmongo/) framework which allows to implement relations by providing @OneToMany and @OneToOne annotations support.

Answer (score 1):

If your relation is not based on `dbref`, you can use `@DocumentReference`
https://spring.io/blog/2021/11/29/spring-data-mongodb-relation-modelling