# Multiple join conditions using the $lookup operator

Tags: mongodb, join, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Have the two following collections:

```
// collection1:
{
  user1: 1,
  user2: 2,
  percent: 0.56
}

// collection2:
{
  user1: 1,
  user2: 2,
  percent: 0.3
}
```

I want to join these two collections on `user1` and `user2`.

How can I write a pipeline in order to get a result like this:

```
{
  user1: 1,
  user2: 2,
  percent1: 0.56,
  percent2: 0.3
}
```

Comment: No you can't join using 'user1" and 'user2' this is simply not possible as both `localField` and `foreignField` take only one field's name.

Comment: I find one way to do it. $out the two collection to a new collection and group it.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

We can do multiple join conditions with the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation pipeline operator in version 3.6 and newer.

We need to assign the fields's values to variable using the `let` optional field; you then access those variables in the `pipeline` field stages where you specify the pipeline to run on the collections.

Note that in the `$match` stage, we use the [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/query/expr/#exp._S_expr) evaluation query operator to compare the fields's value.

The last stage in the pipeline is the [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) aggregation pipeline stage where we simply merge the `$lookup` result with part of the `$$ROOT` document using the [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) operator.

```
db.collection2.aggregate([
       {
          $lookup: {
             from: "collection1",
             let: {
                firstUser: "$user1",
                secondUser: "$user2"
             },
             pipeline: [
                {
                   $match: {
                      $expr: {
                         $and: [
                            {
                               $eq: [
                                  "$user1",
                                  "$$firstUser"
                               ]
                            },
                            {
                               $eq: [
                                  "$user2",
                                  "$$secondUser"
                               ]
                            }
                         ]
                      }
                   }
                }
             ],
             as: "result"
          }
       },
       {
          $replaceRoot: {
             newRoot: {
                $mergeObjects:[
                   {
                      $arrayElemAt: [
                         "$result",
                         0
                      ]
                   },
                   {
                      percent1: "$$ROOT.percent1"
                   }
                ]
             }
          }
       }
    ]
)
```

This pipeline yields something that look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e1ad7d36f42d8960c06022"),
    "user1" : 1,
    "user2" : 2,
    "percent" : 0.3,
    "percent1" : 0.56
}
```

---

If you are not on version 3.6+, you can first join using one of your field let say "user1" then from there you unwind the array of the matching document using the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind) aggregation pipeline operator. The next stage in the pipeline is the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) stage where you filter out those documents where the value of "user2" from the "joined" collection and the input document are not equal using the [`$$KEEP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep) and [`$$PRUNE`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune) system variables. You can then reshape your document in [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project) stage.

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
    { "$lookup": { 
        "from": "collection2", 
        "localField": "user1", 
        "foreignField": "user1", 
        "as": "collection2_doc"
    }}, 
    { "$unwind": "$collection2_doc" },
    { "$redact": { 
        "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$user2", "$collection2_doc.user2" ] }, 
            "$$KEEP", 
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }}, 
    { "$project": { 
        "user1": 1, 
        "user2": 1, 
        "percent1": "$percent", 
        "percent2": "$collection2_doc.percent"
    }}
])
```

which produces:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("572daa87cc52a841bb292beb"),
    "user1" : 1,
    "user2" : 2,
    "percent1" : 0.56,
    "percent2" : 0.3
}
```

---

If the documents in your collections have the same structure and you find yourself performing this operation often, then you should consider to merge the two collections into one or insert the documents in those collections into a new collection.

```
db.collection3.insertMany(
    db.collection1.find({}, {"_id": 0})
    .toArray()
    .concat(db.collection2.find({}, {"_id": 0}).toArray())
)
```

Then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group) your documents by "user1" and "user2"

```
db.collection3.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "user1": "$user1", "user2": "$user2" }, 
        "percent": { "$push": "$percent" }
    }}
])
```

which yields:

```
{ "_id" : { "user1" : 1, "user2" : 2 }, "percent" : [ 0.56, 0.3 ] }
```

Comment: Looking at this makes me appreciate SQL way more than Mongo.

Comment: `{  $match: {  $expr: {   $and: [  {  $eq: [  "$user1",   "$$firstUser"   ]   },    {    $eq:                             $user2",  "$$secondUser"  ]  }  ] } } }` why this is not working?

Comment: @styvane is it possible to aggregate (join with 2 fields) and then filter the result from this join? I could achieve both thngs separetely but not together =\

Answer (score 8):

Starting `Mongo 4.4`, we can achieve this type of "join" with the new [`$unionWith`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/#unionwith-aggregation) aggregation stage coupled with a classic `$group` stage:

```
// > db.collection1.find()
//   { "user1" : 1, "user2" : 2, "percent" : 0.56 }
//   { "user1" : 4, "user2" : 3, "percent" : 0.14 }
// > db.collection2.find()
//   { "user1" : 1, "user2" : 2, "percent" : 0.3  }
//   { "user1" : 2, "user2" : 3, "percent" : 0.25 }
db.collection1.aggregate([
  { $set: { percent1: "$percent" } },
  { $unionWith: {
    coll: "collection2",
    pipeline: [{ $set: { percent2: "$percent" } }]
  }},
  { $group: {
    _id: { user1: "$user1", user2: "$user2" },
    percents: { $mergeObjects: { percent1: "$percent1", percent2: "$percent2" } }
  }}
])
// { _id: { user1: 1, user2: 2 }, percents: { percent1: 0.56, percent2: 0.3 } }
// { _id: { user1: 2, user2: 3 }, percents: { percent2: 0.25 } }
// { _id: { user1: 4, user2: 3 }, percents: { percent1: 0.14 } }
```

This:

- Starts with a union of both collections into the pipeline via the new [`$unionWith`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/#unionwith-aggregation) stage:

  - We first rename `percent` from `collection1` to `percent1` (using a `$set` stage)
  - Within the `$unionWith` stage, we specify a `pipeline` on the `collection2` in order to also rename `percent` this time to `percent2`.
  - This way, we can differentiate the percentage field's origin.
- Continues with a `$group` stage that:

  - Groups records based on `user1` and `user2`
  - Accumulate percentages via a [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/#mergeobjects-aggregation) operation. Using `$first: "$percent1"` and `$first: "$percent2"` wouldn't work since this could potentially take `null` first (for elements from the other collection). Whereas `$mergeObjects` discards `null` values.

If you need a different output format, you can add a downstream `$project` stage.

Answer (score 7):

If you're trying to model your data, and came here to check if mongodb can perform joins on multiple fields before deciding to do so, please read on.

While MongoDB can perform joins, you also have the freedom to model data according to your application access pattern. If the data is as simple as presented in the question, we can simply maintain a single collection that looks like this:

```
{
    user1: 1,
    user2: 2,
    percent1: 0.56,
    percent2: 0.3
}
```

Now you can perform all the operations on this collection you would have performed by joining. Why are we trying to avoid joins? <del>Because they are not supported by sharded collections ([docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)), which will stop you from scaling out when needed.</del> (Joins are now supported in sharded collections) Normalizing data (having separate tables/collections) works very well in SQL, but when it comes to Mongo, avoiding joins can offer advantages without consequences in most cases. Use normalization in MongoDB only when you have no other choice. From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/data-model-design/#normalized-data-models):

> In general, use normalized data models:
>
> - when embedding would result in duplication of data but would not    provide sufficient read performance advantages to outweigh the implications of the duplication.
> - to represent more complex many-to-many relationships.
> - to model large hierarchical data sets.

Check [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/data-model-design/#embedded-data-models) to read more about embedding and why you would choose it over normalization.

Answer (score 4):

You can do mutiple field matches using **$match** and **$project** pipelines. (see detailed answer here - [mongoDB Join on multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43479962/5418136))

```js
db.collection1.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'collection2',
      localField: 'user1',
      foreignField: 'user1',
      as: 'c2',
    },
  },
  { $unwind: '$c2' },

  {
    $project: {
      user2Eq: { $eq: ['$user2', '$c2.user2'] },
      user1: 1,
      user2: 1,
      percent1: '$percent',
      percent2: '$c2.percent',
    },
  },

  {
    $match: {
      user2Eq: { $eq: true },
    },
  },

  {
    $project: {
      user2Eq: 0,
    },
  },
])
```