# mongoDB Join on multiple fields

Tags: mongodb

I am rewriting SQL Queries into mongoDB. Can someone help how do we join two collections with multiple join keys and conditions like in below SQL Query.

```
SELECT S.* FROM LeftTable S
LEFT JOIN RightTable R ON S.ID =R.ID AND S.MID =R.MID WHERE R.TIM >0 AND S.MOB IS NOT NULL
```

I have the below code which does with single join key condition. I would be glad if someone can help with multiple join keys and where clause to complete query.

```
db.dim.aggregate([{$lookup:{from:"dimFactsVer11",localField:"Sub", foreignField:"Type", as:"EmbedUp"}}])
```

Comment: This may be a good starting point: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/joins-and-other-aggregation-enhancements-coming-in-mongodb-3-2-part-1-of-3-introduction

Comment: have already the referred the post which has helped me to build part of the above query. The post doesn't speak about joining with multiple keys which I am looking for now.

Comment: Is this not possible in mongoDB?

Comment: Does anyone have any clue on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently mongodb **$lookup** only compare single **local** and **foreign** key.

But if you want to perform a query as like mysql left join with two or more filed then below is solution.

```
db.getCollection('LeftTable').aggregate([
{
    $lookup:
        {
          from: "RightTable",
          localField: "ID",
          foreignField: "ID",
          as: "RightTableData"
        }
},  
{$unwind :"$RightTableData" },
{ 
     $project: { 
            mid: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ '$MID', '$RightTableData.MID' ] }, 1, 0 ] } 
        } 
},
{$match : { mid : 1}}

])
```

Here $MID is **LeftTable** MID field.

Answer (score 4):

With right combination of **$lookup**, **$project** and **$match**, you can join mutiple tables on parameters. This is because they can be chained multiple times.

**Step 1: Link all tables**

**$lookup** - one for each table in query

**$unwind** - because data is denormalised correctly, else wrapped in arrays

Python code..

```
db.LeftTable.aggregate([
                        # connect all tables

                        {"$lookup": {
                          "from": "RightTable",
                          "localField": "ID",
                          "foreignField": "ID",
                          "as": "R"
                        }},
                        {"$unwind": "R"}

                       # {"$lookup": {
                       #   "from": "TopTable",
                       #   "localField": "ID",
                       #   "foreignField": "ID",
                       #   "as": "T"
                       # }},
                       # {"$unwind": "T"},

                        ])
```

**Step 2: Define all conditionals**

**$project** : define all conditional statements here, plus all the variables you'd like to select.

Python Code..

```
db.LeftTable.aggregate([
                        # connect all tables

                        {"$lookup": {
                          "from": "RightTable",
                          "localField": "ID",
                          "foreignField": "ID",
                          "as": "R"
                        }},
                        {"$unwind": "R"},

                       # {"$lookup": {
                       #   "from": "TopTable",
                       #   "localField": "ID",
                       #   "foreignField": "ID",
                       #   "as": "T"
                       # }},
                       # {"$unwind": "T"},

                        # define conditionals + variables

                        {"$project": {
                          "midEq": {"$eq": ["$MID", "$R.MID"]},
                         # "midGt": {"$gt": ["$MID", "$T.MID"]},
                          "ID": 1, "MOB": 1, "MID": 1
                        }}
                        ])
```

**Step 3: Join all the conditionals**

**$match** - join all conditions using OR or AND etc. There can be multiples of these.

**$project**: undefine all conditionals

Python Code..

```
db.LeftTable.aggregate([
                        # connect all tables

                        {"$lookup": {
                          "from": "RightTable",
                          "localField": "ID",
                          "foreignField": "ID",
                          "as": "R"
                        }},
                        {"$unwind": "$R"},

                       # {"$lookup": {
                        #  "from": "TopTable",
                        #  "localField": "ID",
                        #  "foreignField": "ID",
                        #  "as": "T"
                        #}},
                        #{"$unwind": "$T"},

                        # define conditionals + variables

                        {"$project": {
                          "midEq": {"$eq": ["$MID", "$R.MID"]},
                          # "midGt": {"$gt": ["$MID", "$T.MID"]},
                          "ID": 1, "MOB": 1, "MID": 1
                        }},

                        # join all conditionals

                        {"$match": {
                          "$and": [
                            {"R.TIM": {"$gt": 0}}, 
                            {"MOB": {"$exists": True}},
                            {"midEq": {"$eq": True}},]
                        }},

                        # undefine conditionals

                        {"$project": {
                          "midEq": 0,
                          # "midGt": 0
                        }}

                        ])
```

Pretty much any combination of tables, conditionals and joins can be done in this manner.