# Merge multi documents using MongoDB under multi conditions

Tags: mongodb

I have followed the below SO thread but still not functioning.

[MongoDB Join on multiple fields [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224981/mongodb-join-on-multiple-fields)

[Multiple join conditions using the $lookup operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086387/multiple-join-conditions-using-the-lookup-operator)

My `collection1` is as below:

```
{ 
   _id: 5bc2e44a106342152cd83e97,
   description:
            { 
              status: 'Good',
              machine: 'X',
             },
   order: 'A',
   lot: '1' 
}
```

My `collection2` is as follow:

```
{
   _id: 5bc2e44a106342152cd83e80,
   isCompleted: false,
   serialNo: '1',
   batchNo: '2',
   product: [{ 
              order: 'A', lot: '1',
              order: 'A', lot: '2'
            }]
}
```

the result i expect is as follow:

```
{ 
   _id: 5bc2e44a106342152cd83e97,
   description:
            { 
              status: 'Good',
              machine: 'X',
             },
   order: 'A',
   lot: '1' ,
   isCompleted: false,
   serialNo: '1',
   batchNo: '2'
}
```

The aggregation operation has to be based on the condition where `product` array in `collection2` contains the `order` and `lot` that is the same with the `order` and `lot` in `collection1`.

Below are 2 codes that I have tried but to no avail. May I have some guidance.

```
db.collection2.aggregate([
              { $unwind : "$product" }
              {
                    $lookup: {
                          from: "collection1",
                          localField: "product.order",
                          foreignField: "order",
                          as: "results"
                    }
              },
              {
                    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$results", 0 ] }, "$$ROOT" ] } }
              }]
```

Then, I tried the multiple join condition based on the docs, but no luck

```
db.collection2.aggregate([
              { $unwind : "$product" },
              { $lookup: {
                     from: "collection1",
                     let: { order: "$order", lot: "$lot" },
                     pipeline: [
                           {
                                 $match: {
                                       $expr: {
                                             $and: [
                                                   { $eq: [ "$product.order", "$$order" ] },
                                                   { $eq: [ "$product.lot", "$$lot"] }
                                                   ]
                                             }
                                       }
                                 }
                           ],
                           as: "results"
                     }
               },
              {
                    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$results", 0 ] }, "$$ROOT" ] } }
              }]
```

Any hints or guidance or solution will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, just a small mix with the referenced fields in the lookup:

```
{
    from: "collection1",
    let: { order: "$product.order", lot: "$product.lot" },
    pipeline: [
       {
         $match: {
                  $expr: {
                          $and: [
                                 { $eq: [ "$order", "$$order" ] },
                                 { $eq: [ "$lot", "$$lot"] }
                                ]
                          }
                 }
       }],
    as: "results"
}
```

this will work for u :)

Comment: Hi, I just noticed the blunder I did there. However, the results came back
`results: [ [Object] ]`. How can I expand the object field to check whether the data has been passed in correctly?

This is because the condition is still not fulfilled. It just bind the `collection1` field to every single `product` array in `collection2`

Comment: the results are, as usual, array of the "joined" documents (hence 'Object'). unwind the results , and add another projection step if u wish , though I would implement the last projection in the code instead of adding more steps to the pipeline .

Comment: ok, can i ask if I were to maintain my reference but i start with `db.collection1.aggregate` instead, how can i lookup the reference value in `collection2` in the `$lookup`. I got back an empty result if i do it in this reverse way, I think the main issue is that i need to do `$unwind` as well in this case, but I have no idea how to use `$unwind` inside `$lookup`

Comment: if  you go from col1 to col2 than you'll need to do $elemMatch for the joining condition, and unwind again and again. where/how do you use the results of your query? (I'm trying to understand why you insists to get final organized results and not manipulating them by code)

Comment: i'm just curious on how it works from another point of view. Anyway, thanks a lot !. I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your document structure looks like this:

```
{
    _id: 5bc2e44a106342152cd83e80,
    isCompleted: false,
    serialNo: '1',
    batchNo: '2',
    product: [ // note the subdocuments here
        { order: 'A', lot: '1' },
        { order: 'A', lot: '2' }
    ]
}
```

You can run this to get the desired result:

```
db.collection1.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "collection2",
        let: { order: "$order", lot: "$lot" },
        pipeline: [{
            $match: {
                $expr:  { $in: [ { order: "$$order", lot: "$$lot" }, "$product"] }
            }
        }],
        as: "isCompleted" // we're just using the "isCompleted" field in order to avoid having to remove some "results" (or something) field later
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        "isCompleted": { $arrayElemAt: [ "$isCompleted", 0 ] } // take the first matched document only
    }
}, {
    $addFields: { // add the required fields to the top level structure
        "isCompleted": "$isCompleted.isCompleted", // here, we set the "isCompleted" field to its real value
        "serialNo": "$isCompleted.serialNo",
        "batchNo": "$isCompleted.batchNo"
    }
}])
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your code, however the result only return what `collection1` has in the first place.

Comment: Yes, indeed, this way you wouldn't get any results for the documents in `collection2` that do not have anything in their `product` array. If that is a valid data setup for you then this solution won't work nicely. If you can be sure that such a case doesn't exist (as in: "a shopping cart does never exist without any items in it") then this solution here will be nice because it avoids the slow `$unwind`.

Comment: i see. My scenario is that `collection1` will always exists regardless if `collection2` contains that particular product or not. `collection2` is meant to be added separately for the purpose of grouping the products under this `serialNo` and `batchNo`. My purpose of using `aggregate` is to acutally join the data back where the products from both collection matches. Nonetheless, the same `product` in both collections will have different `_id` assigned as a result

Comment: I was tricked into believing that you actually *wanted* to start from `collection1` because of the sample output that you asked for which has `_id: ObjectId("5bc2e44a106342152cd83e97")` which in fact is the one you mentioned for the example document in `collection1`.

Comment: sorry about that. I'm  guessing it should still work though. But the id wise may not be though.