# MongoDB lookup by 2 or more fields (columns)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In SQL it looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM cats_dat_ref
LEFT OUTER JOIN cats_dat_parts 
    ON cats_dat_ref.cat_folder = cats_dat_parts.cat_folder 
    AND cats_dat_ref.ref = cats_dat_parts.ref
```

I have:

```
db.cdr.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "cdp",
            localField: "cat_folder",
            foreignField: "cat_folder",
            as: "cdp"
        }
    }, {
        $project: {
            ....
        }
    }
]).forEach(function (item) {
    ...
});
```

How do I add the second condition in lookup for `ref = ref` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join two collections on mutiple field using $lookup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086387/how-to-join-two-collections-on-mutiple-field-using-lookup)

Comment: Yes, it is! Thanks for help!