# How to Join Arrays in the Same Document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql

I would like to combine the data in one collection using the IDs of the two arrays.

An example is shown below.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId ("5976fd2eb0adec0a32fa9831"),
       "People": [
          {
            "_id": 1,      <--- ID
            "Name": "jane"
          },
          {
            "_id": 2,      <--- ID
            "Name": "Mark"
          }
       ],
       "Contents": [
          {
            "userID":  2,   <--- People ID
            "Text": "111"
          },
          {
            "userID":  1,   <--- People ID
            "Text": "Hi"
          }
       ]
}
```

I want to make the above document as below.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId ("5976fd2eb0adec0a32fa9831"),
    "People": [
       {
          "_id": 1,
          "Name" : "Jane"
       },
       {
          "_id": 2,
          "Name": "Mark"
       }
    ],
    "Contents": [
       {
          "userID": 2,
          "Name": "Mark",    <-- Adding
          "Text": "111",

      },
       {
          "userID": 1,
          "Name": "Jane",    <-- Adding
          "Text": "Hi",

      }
    ]
}
```

I have tried various things like `$lookup` or `$unwind` of `.aggregate()` but I cannot get the result.

Comment: Have you tried this links ?? I hope it would help , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086387/join-two-collections-on-mutiple-field-using-lookup   and https://www.sitepoint.com/using-joins-in-mongodb-nosql-databases/

Comment: @Tehmina There should be no need to "self-join" between items in the same document. It would be really inefficient and there actually are very effective ways of doing this, without needing to effectively "re-query" the collection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) ideally:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "Contents": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$Contents",
        "as": "c",
        "in": {
          "userID": "$$c.userID",
          "Name": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$People.Name",
              { "$indexOfArray": [ "$People._id", "$$c.userID" ] }
            ]
          },
          "Text": "$$c.Text"
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Which basically grabs the value from the other array via [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) for the matching "index" returned by [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/).

If your MongoDB needs to fall back a version without that operator, then you could use [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) instead:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "Contents": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$Contents",
        "as": "c",
        "in": {
          "userID": "$$c.userID",
          "Name": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              { "$map": {
                "input": { 
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$People",
                    "as": "p",
                    "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$p._id", "$$c.userID" ] }
                  }
                },
                "as": "p",
                "in": "$$p.Name"
              }},
              0
            ]
          },
          "Text": "$$c.Text"
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Where basically you [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) the results down of the other array in comparison and simply return the **first** matching element by the `0` index with [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/).

In either case, there is no need to "self-join" using [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), and that's just really unnecessary overhead best avoided.

From the document in the question you get the following:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976fd2eb0adec0a32fa9831"),
    "People" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1.0,
            "Name" : "jane"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 2.0,
            "Name" : "Mark"
        }
    ],
    "Contents" : [ 
        {
            "userID" : 2.0,
            "Name" : "Mark",
            "Text" : "111"
        }, 
        {
            "userID" : 1.0,
            "Name" : "jane",
            "Text" : "Hi"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Generally speaking though, there is no such reason for any aggregation operators at all, as this sort of operation is generally best left to post-processing in the cursor. In fact since you are actually "adding" data to the document to return, it's better to do modification after the document is sent over the network.

As a common idiom of the above shown as JavaScript for the shell:

```
db.collection.find().map( d => 
  Object.assign(
    d,
    {
      "Contents": d.Contents.map( c => 
        Object.assign(c, 
          { "Name": d.People.map(p => p.Name)[d.People.map(p => p._id).indexOf(c.userID)] }
        )
      )
    }
  )
)
```

Produces the exact same result, and is generally a bit easier on the eyes to read and interpret