# How to join two collections in mongo Db?

Tags: mongodb

I've created two collections one for **people details** and another for their **income, spending amount etc**.

i want cumulative result how to combine both collections??

Comment: Hi Sudharsana Viswanathan; can you [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert all documents from one collection into another.  Here is how to do that using the mongo shell:

```
db.collection1.find().forEach( function(x){db.collection2.insert(x)} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of combining them into one collection (which may or may not be correct in your situation - no way of knowing) take a look at this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813854/how-to-join-multiple-collections-with-lookup-mongodb). Also you should seriously study both the [lookup and aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) possibilities in MongoDB. Since Mongo is NoSQL the way we approach lookup information is a bit different.