# How to find Intersection of Two Collection in monogdb?

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework, phalcon

Let say, I have 2 collection

first one :-

> db.product_main

```js
{
  _id:123121,
  source_id:"B4456dde1",
  title:"test Sample",
  price: 250
  quantity: 40
}
```

which consist approx ~10000 objects (Array) and unique field is source_id.

Second :-

> db.product_id

```js
{
  "_id":58745633,
  "product_id":"B4456dde1"
}
```

which consist of ~500 and only have field "product_id" which is equals to "source_id" of db.product_main

now, i want to intersect two collection so that i only find those which don't exist in db.product_id.

> db.product_main.aggregate({any query})

Comment: Please add the example document structure of each collection and post what have you tried so far

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join multiple collections with $lookup in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813854/how-to-join-multiple-collections-with-lookup-in-mongodb)

Comment: my main objective is not to join but to find data which id do not exists in 2 table.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the lookup stage to find the products associated with the 'product_main' collection and then match for empty array (i.e. records where no product_id was found)

```
db.product_main.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "product_id",
      localField: "source_id",
      foreignField: "product_id",
      as: "products_available"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      products_available: {
        $size: 0
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

On `WRITE` operations using aggregate pipeline You can also directly offload statistics update by using `$out` command and store cached result in `product_stats` collection (for example).

Later in web/ui/api `READ` operations just use this cached collection. Of cause, You can create database query methods for cached and non-cached results.