# how to join collection from mongodb using python

Tags: python, mongodb

I have 3 collections of 'Demo' cluster: 
want to join all columns from these 3 tables. 
as
**data**

```
{
"email":"jhelliar0@techcrunch.com",
"first_name":"Silvanus",
"last_name":"Spikins",
"mobile":"5279757399",
"car_model":"2500",
"car_color":"Orange",
"company_name":"Fanoodle",
"Desiganation":"Recruiter",
"country":"Georgia",
"city":"Marneuli"
}
```

**Tables are:**

**emp_login**

```
{
"_id":"$oid":"5e9435ff61a03e23fc7bdb64"},
"id":"1",
"email":"jhelliar0@techcrunch.com",
"password":"diOIE0qd3j"
}
```

**employee**

```
{
"_id":"$oid":"5e940eda61a03e23fc7bd392"},
"email":"jhelliar0@techcrunch.com",
"first_name":"Silvanus",
"last_name":"Spikins",
"mobile":"5279757399",
"car_model":"2500",
"car_color":"Orange"
}
```

**company**

```
{
"_id":"$oid":"5e940eb161a03e23fc7bcfa9"},
"email":"jhelliar0@techcrunch.com",
"company_name":"Fanoodle",
"Desiganation":"Recruiter",
"country":"Georgia",
"city":"Marneuli"
}
```

use **email and password** for login from emp_login cluster and after that join all related data from these clusters as shows above in **data** table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join multiple collections with $lookup in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813854/how-to-join-multiple-collections-with-lookup-in-mongodb)

Comment: yes I try this, but it doesn't work for me