# How to query two collections with related data?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 2 collections, collection A has some documents like `{'id':1,'field':'name'}`,`{'id':1,'field':'age'}`，and collection B has some documents like
`{'_id':1,'name':'alice','age':18,'phone':123}`,`{'_id':2,'name':'bob','age':30,'phone':321}`

and I want to find all the document whose '_id' is in collectionA, and just project the corresponding field.

for example:

collection A

```
{'id':1,'field':'name'},
{'id':1,'field':'age'}
```

collection B

```
{'_id':1,'name':'alice','age':18,'phone':123},
{'_id':2,'name':'bob','age':30,'phone':321}
```

the result is:

```
{'name':'alice','age':18},
```

I don't know if there is an easy way to do that？

Comment: You can try using a single aggregation query with a [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage. Here is one similar post: [How to join multiple collections with $lookup in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813854/how-to-join-multiple-collections-with-lookup-in-mongodb).

Comment: @zxCoder Sorry the output was wrong in the first attempt. Check the updated query with output, also what is your MongoDB version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $lookup to join two collection

```
db.col1.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "col2",
      "localField": "id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "listNames"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      listNames: {
        $first: "$listNames"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: "$listNames.name",
      age: "$listNames.age"
    }
  }
])
```

Mongo Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/E-0WvK_SUS_

Answer (score 0):

So the idea is:

1. Convert the documents in to key, value pair for both the collections using [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/).
2. Then perform a join operation based on key `k` and (`id` <-> `_id`) using [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).
3. Replace the result as root element using [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/).
4. Convert array to object using [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) and again `$replaceRoot`.

Query:

```js
db.colB.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            temp: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "colA",
            let: { temp: "$temp", colB_id: "$_id" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $addFields: {
                        temp: { k: "$field", v: "$id" }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $and: [
                                { $in: ["$temp.k", "$$temp.k"] },
                                { $eq: ["$temp.v", "$$colB_id"] }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $replaceRoot: {
                        newRoot: {
                            $first: {
                                $filter: {
                                    input: "$$temp",
                                    as: "item",
                                    cond: { $eq: ["$field", "$$item.k"] }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "array"
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$array" }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```js
{
    "name" : "alice",
    "age" : 18
}
```