# Issuing mongoose queries on unpopulated subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user Schema defined as follows:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true},
  blogs: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Blog'}],
});
```

The blog Schema is as follows:

```
var BlogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    owner: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId},
});
```

What I would like to do is issue a `find` query that, given a string q, will find all users whose usernames contains q OR who has at least one blog whose name contains q.

This is my code so far:

```
User.find({
            $or: [ {username:{$regex: q, $options: 'i'}}, 
                {blogs:{ $elemMatch: {name: {$regex: q, $options: 'i'}}}}]
        })
        .exec(function(err,users){
            if (err) {return next(err);}
            res.json(users);
        });
```

However the above doesn't work. If I have a user, `lizard`, with a blog, `TheReptilian`, looking with "rep" as the q parameter doesn't bring up `lizard`.

The reason why I think that is because the `blogs` array of my `UserSchema` is effectively an array of ObjectID's. How can I make this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I query referenced objects in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621928/how-do-i-query-referenced-objects-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two-steps query:

```
Blog.find({name: {$regex: q, $options: 'i'}).exec(function(err, blogs){
    if (err) {return next(err);}
    User.find({
        $or: [ {username:{$regex: q, $options: 'i'}}, 
            {blogs:{ $in: blogs} }]
    }).exec(function(err,users){
        if (err) {return next(err);}
        res.json(users);
    });
});
```