# How to use Joins in MongoDB Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

hi all i using mongoDB two tables . will stored one table(Elevator Master) id to another table(Elevator Mapping)  now i get that relevant elevator id name from Elevator Master in mongo DB here i attached the query help to solve
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Try [Mongoose Populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: i don't know about that @gaganshera help how to use and solve this problem i am new for mongodb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I query referenced objects in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621928/how-do-i-query-referenced-objects-in-mongodb)