# how do i,if possible, other ways, rename a returned field in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

i have this query:

```
MessageModel.find({ conversationId: { $in: ids } })
            .sort({createdAt: 'ascending'})
            .populate({ path: 'receiver', select: '_id' })
            .populate({ path: 'sender', select: '_id' });
```

reveicer and sender will return same id fields? I want to rename the _id equal to relevant receiverId and senderId?

Comment: You would have to change the names you store in the database, so alter the fields _id to  eg reciever_id and sender_id

Comment: @MirzaS in the model? right? I was hoping I can do it on query

Comment: If the fields in the database are named like reciever_id and sender_id, just change them in the model, if not, you'll need to change them in the db also

Comment: @MirzaS thanks i was confused. this' very helpful to me as newbie

Comment: No problem, I'll post it as an answer so you can close your question

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [$lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621928/how-do-i-query-referenced-objects-in-mongodb/39476690#39476690) instead of populate

```
MessageModel.aggregate({$match:{ conversationId: { $in: ids } }},
{$lookup: {
  from: 'receiver',
  localField:'receiver',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'receiver'
}},
{$unwind:'$receiver'},
{$lookup: {
  from: 'sender',
  localField:'sender',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'sender'
}},
{$unwind:'$sender'}

)
```