# How to perform an expensive "relational" query in MongoDB using Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am doing sales analysis of users for an e-commerce that uses mongo and I found this problem of performance:

I need to know how much a bunch of users, filtered by creation date, have spent in certain product.

Simplifying my user model looks like this

```
var userSchema = Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String
})
```

And simplyfing the orders model looks like this:

```
const orderSchema = Schema({
    totalAmount: String,
    user: ObjectId, 
    products: {
        reference: [
            {product: ObjectId, quantity: 3},
            {product: ObjectId, quantity: 2}
        ]
    }
})
```

there is no reference from the user schema to the order schema, so for an array with 8000 users to fetch one by one async looking for all the orders with each user Id and then checking within the orders if they has the target product. Let alone doing global calculations..

This takes forever in mongo so it won´t work for me. Is there any idea for improving performance in this situation?

Comment: 1) search orders for which products you need
2) search users based on the userId from the found orders
3) do calculations on data sets

Comment: Sounds like a plan @VtoCorleone Thanks!

Comment: take a look at $lookup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621928/how-do-i-query-referenced-objects-in-mongodb/39476690#39476690