# how to use mongoose pagination with populate and query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pagination

I'm trying use mongoose pagination to process advance search with pagination.

I have the following schemas:

```
const authorSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: {type: String, unique: true},
});    
const Author = mongoose.model('author', authorSchema, 'author');

const bookSchema = Schema({
_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
name: String,
authors:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'author'}]
});
const Book= mongoose.model('book', bookSchema , 'book');
```

I want to find 24 book for page 1 with any book contains author name 'jean'. I do the following with [mongoose-paginate](https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/mongoose-paginate) module:

```
 Book.paginate({}, {
    page: 1,
    limit: 24,
    populate: {
     path: 'authors',
     select: 'name',
     match: {
        name: 'jean'
     }
    }, function (err, books) {
        res.json(books);
    });
```

But the result books contains other book with authors array empty. I cant use books.filter() to remove book with authors. But if i do that, i can't have 24 book per page on result.

What is the right way to do that?

Comment: I think is not possible. There is another package for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of populate, I suggest to use [`$lookup`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621928/how-do-i-query-referenced-objects-in-mongodb/39476690#39476690) in aggregation query.

```
db.book.aggregate(
{$unwind:'$authors'},
{$lookup:{
    from: 'author',
    localField: 'authors',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'authors'
    }},
    {$unwind: '$authors'},
    {$match: {'authors.name':'Jean'}},
    {$group: {_id: '$_id', authors: {$push: '$authors'}}},
    {$limit: 24}
)
```

`populate` was an old solution before `$lookup` support, and we should strive to use latest DB features.

Comment: This does not use the mongoose-paginate module, can you show an answer with the module.

Comment: don't understand the downvotes. Users need to figure out whether they want a solution to a problem that doesn't require any library or want to use specific library

Comment: The user does mentions that is library specific.

Comment: then it becomes a XY problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem