# Is it possible to populate a field in mongoose which has other information on it too?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

This is the relevant portion of my Schema:

```
var classroomSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    students: [{
        _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        rate: {
            type: Number,
            default: 200,
        },
        referrals: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    }],
)};
```

Here rate and referrals are properties of the students which are valid in the context of that classroom, and cannot be populated from the Students model.

Is there any way to define my schema such that I can keep those fields(rate and referrals) and also use populate to link other fields such as name, age, etc of the student?

Comment: Take a look at `$lookup` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621928/how-do-i-query-referenced-objects-in-mongodb/39476690#39476690

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your schema to this:

```
var classroomSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    students: [{
        rate: { type: Number, default: 200 },

        user: { ref: 'User', type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
        referrals: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    }],
});
```

Usage:

```
classroom
  .findOne(...)
  .populate('user')
  .exec((err, classroom) => {
    let student0 = classroom.students[0];
    // student0.rate
    // student0.user.name
  });
```

Comment: Is there a better way? Saving a user field in the students arraay which is supposed to be an array of users seems unnatural to me.

Comment: The `user` field is just a reference to the `User`. This is the most natural way if a user can be added into multiple classrooms.