# Mongoose sub doc referencing another sub doc

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I've got a `customer` schema with two sub-doc sets; `orders`, and `children`, which looks like this:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

const childrenSchema = new Schema({
 'firstname': { 'type': String, 'required': true },
 'lastname': { 'type': String, 'required': true },
 'class': { 'type': String, 'required': true },
 'school': { 'type': ObjectId, 'ref': 'Schools', 'required': true }
});

mongoose.model('Children', childrenSchema);

const ordersSchema = new Schema({
 'date': { 'type': Date, 'required': true },
 'delivery': { 'type': Date, 'required': true },
 'item': { 'type': ObjectId, 'ref': 'Foods', 'required': true },
 'child': { 'type': ObjectId, 'ref': 'Children', 'required': true }
});

mongoose.model('Orders', ordersSchema);

const customersSchema = new Schema({
 'contact': {
  'firstname': { 'type': String, 'required': true },
  'lastname': { 'type': String, 'required': true },
  'address': {
   'road': { 'type': String, 'required': true },
   'number': { 'type': String, 'required': true },
   'floor': String,
   'door': String,
   'city': { 'type': String, 'required': true },
   'zipcode': { 'type': String, 'required': true }
  },
  'email': { 'type': String, 'index': { 'unique': true }, 'required': true },
  'phone': String
 },
 'password': { 'type': String, 'required': true },
 'balance': { 'type': Number, 'default': 0.00 },
 'active': { 'type': Boolean, 'default': false },
 'children': [childrenSchema],
 'orders': [ordersSchema]
});

mongoose.model('Customers', customersSchema);
```

Now, my problem is, that the Customers.orders.child doesn't populate correctly when I do a simple find and populate:

```
Customers.find()
    .select('-password')
    .populate('orders.item orders.child orders.child.school children.school')
    .exec((err, result) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Sample result:

```
{
    "_id": "59cbb8335b5cdb08f85879b7",
    "__v": 1,
    "orders": [
        {
            "date": "2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z",
            "delivery": "2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z",
            "item": {
                "_id": "59cbd9c78142782c30285bde",
                "name": "Laksesandwich",
                "description": "Saftig frisk laks i en hjemmebagt speltbolle med salat og dressing.",
                "price": 38.5,
                "__v": 0,
                "image": "placeholder.png"
            },
            "child": null,
            "_id": "59cbfe9f36b937296cbc76be"
        }
    ],
    "children": [
        {
            "firstname": "Ole",
            "lastname": "Erling",
            "class": "8A",
            "school": {
                "_id": "59cb876d7c700ec255eeb04d",
                "name": "Københavns Skole",
                "address": {
                    "road": "Københavnsvej",
                    "number": "133",
                    "city": "København",
                    "zipcode": "2000"
                }
            },
            "_id": "59cbb8335b5cdb08f85879b8"
        }
    ],
    "active": false,
    "balance": 0,
    "contact": {
        "firstname": "Albert",
        "lastname": "Einstein",
        "email": "genius@gmail.com",
        "address": {
            "road": "Hovedgaden",
            "number": "42",
            "city": "København",
            "zipcode": "2000"
        }
    }
}
```

orders.child is `null`, but should be a populated document of the child which _id is given.

How do I manage this?

Comment: You should use `$lookup` instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621928/how-do-i-query-referenced-objects-in-mongodb/39476690#39476690

Comment: @sidgate does $lookup require I use aggregate instead of find?

Comment: yes, aggregation required

Comment: @sidgate alright, thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure how this helps with sub documents and sub-sub documents. Or I don't understand how aggregate works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Customers.find()
    .select('-password')
    .populate('orders.item children.school')
    .populate({
        path: 'orders.child',
        model: 'Children',
        populate: {
            path: 'orders.child.school',
            model: 'Schools'
        }
    })
    .exec((err, result) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
    });
```

You have to nest populate for nested ref to docs.