# node js, mongodb populate the populated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've hit a wall in my server when I needed to get data from my server.
The following represents my schemas:

```
Schema one:{
name: String
}
Schema two:{
code:String,
name_id: refid: schema One
}
Schema three:{
phone:number
code:[refid: Schema two]
}
```

If I needed data from schema three, and the objects from object ids that are saved in the code array I would use populate and I would get the object referenced by object id.
Question is is it possible to populate the populated data?
If populate schema three
I would get objects such as:

```
{phone : 000911,
code: :{code:String,
name_id: refid: schema One}
```

in the previous example I want to populate the name id, is that possible?

Comment: Try using $lookup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621928/how-do-i-query-referenced-objects-in-mongodb/39476690#39476690

Comment: Is Schema three _code_: refid: Schema One or Two ? Also are you using Mongoose ?

Comment: schema three code is referenced from schema two, yes am using mongoose

Answer (score 1):

With Mongoose, you can populate your schema with dot notation like this:

```
const One = new Schema({
  name: String
})

const Two = new Schema({
  code: String,
  name: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'One'
  }
})

const Three = new Schema({
  phone: number
  code: [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Two'
  }]
})


Three.find((err, three) => {
  if (err) console.log(err)
  console.log(three)  
  // => {
  //      phone : "the phone number from schema Three",
  //      code: {
  //        code: "the code from schema Two",
  //        name: "the name from schema One"
  //      }
  //    }
})
.populate('code.name')
```

Comment: and if i needed a another population, let's say a zero schema, and i needed to populate from three to two to one zero

Comment: That will work with an array too. If you need to add a third level, simply add another dot property. See [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).