# Query from nested object fields - Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I don't know if my question was already asked, but I didn't find any. 
I need to query an object using the fields from nested objects. 
Let me explain this by using images.
[image]

In image 1, you can see an "object type" called dialogcontext which refers another collection in my database. 
So, I know that with populate function I can get the tested object fields, but I need to create a query using those nested fields.

[image]

Something like this:

```
 let detailWeb = await Interaction.aggregate([
            { $match: { dateAdded: { $gte: start, $lt: end } } },
            {
                "$group": {
                    _id: { "dialogcontext.channel": "Web" },
                    data: { $sum: 1 }
                }
            },
            { $sort: { _id: 1 } }]).exec();
```

Do you have any idea or suggestion ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $lookup can be used here. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-aggregation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I query referenced objects in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621928/how-do-i-query-referenced-objects-in-mongodb)