# How to populate documents from other collection. Specific case

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

How to get data from a query that involves 2 collections:
**customers** and **addresses**

I need to get all customers with all addresses for all of them, querying to customers collection.

Using mongoose these are the 2 schemas:

**addressescustomers:**

```
var Customer = require('./customer');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var addressSchema = Schema({
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        unique: false
    },
    customer: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Customer'
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Addresscustomer', addressSchema, 'addressescustomers');
```

**customers:**

```
var Addresscustomer = require ('./addresscustomer');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var customerSchema = Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        unique: false
    },
    address: {
        type: Array,
        ref: 'Addresscustomer'
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Customer', customerSchema, 'customers');
```

I need to execute the query to customers, what I do is this:

```
Customer.find({}, function (err, customers) {
            Addresscustomer.populate(customers, { path: "address" }, function (err, customers) {
                console.log('Customers: '+ customers);
            });
        });
```

Or:

```
var query = Customer.find({}).populate('address');
query.exec(function (err, customers) {
        console.log('Customers: '+ customers);
    });
```

But the key **address** in customers collection is not filled.
Can you tell me how to set correctly the schemas and the query to get the correct data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I query referenced objects in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621928/how-do-i-query-referenced-objects-in-mongodb)

Comment: @sidgate It's not a duplicate, the correct reference is in addressescustomers with: type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Customer' } and I need to do the query from the customers collection not from addressescustomers, one customer has many addresses. Is it possible to do it with Mongoose's populate() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to populate address reference. Since Mongo 3.4 $lookup [works](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22881) on array field as well.

```
db.customers.aggregate([
    { "$lookup": {
       "from": "addressescustomers",
       "localField": "address",
       "foreignField": "_id",
       "as": "addr"
    }}
])
```

Comment: This's the solution, although for my specific case: I set like this:
db.customers.aggregate([
    { "$lookup": {
       "from": "addressescustomers",
       "localField": "_id",
       "foreignField": "customer",
       "as": "addr"
    }}
])