# Mongodb aggregation with referred collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to get a list of my second level affiliate users, I've designed the collection like

user

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1b9df7bfdbfef2d4f1e9f3"), 
    "name" : "name 1",
    "affKey" : "H1g-CfFxG", 
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1bce5e9a2918f71a9ac4fb"), 
    "name" : "name 2",
    "affKey" : "K1gKJfFxG", 
}
```

affilites

```
{  
    "affKey" : "H1g-CfFxG", 
    "affUsers" : [ 
        ObjectId("5a1bce5e9a2918f71a9ac4fb")
    ], 
}

{  
    "affKey" : "K1gKJfFxG", 
    "affUsers" : [
        ObjectId("5a1b9e43bfdbfef2d4f1e9f8"),
        ObjectId("5a1b9e43bfdbfef2d4f1e911"),
    ], 
}
```

Here I am saving a new set in `affiliate.affKey` is based on `Users.affKey`

Now I want to get a list of my first and second level affiliates, i.e. the list of affiliates of `5a1b9e43bfdbfef2d4f1e9f6` and `5a1bce5e9a2918f71a9ac4fb` along with first level affiliate.

expecting the results like

```
{
  first: [first level affiliates] // 1 result 
  second: [second level affiliates] // 2 results
}
```

Comment: If you want to get all affiliate user from `user` collection then you have to use `$lookup`

Comment: @ShaishabRoy any help is appreciated.

Comment: what you mean by first level and second level affiliates ?

Comment: @ShaishabRoy in my example `name 1` is having `name 2` as referral right? Likewise I want to get a list of `name 2`'s referral which is `name 1`'s second level referral.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I query referenced objects in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621928/how-do-i-query-referenced-objects-in-mongodb)

Comment: ok so for second user (name 2) what will be the second level ref ?

Comment: @ShaishabRoy same `affKey` but I dont need that loop, only need level 1 and level 2 of a particular user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this situation you have to some steps to get expected result. can follow bellow steps

> 1. `$lookup` the `affiliets` collection for `affKey`
> 2. Then you have to `$lookup` the `users` collection to get the reference user information
> 3. After that you have to `$lookup` again the `affiliets` collection for second level user `affKey`

so query can be like bellow

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "affilites",
      localField: "affKey",
      foreignField: "affKey",
      as: "affUsers"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      affKey: 1,
      first: {$arrayElemAt: ["$affUsers.affUsers", 0]},
      secondLevelUserId: {$arrayElemAt: ["$affUsers.affUsers", 0]}
    }
  },
  { $unwind: { path: "$secondLevelUserId", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true }},
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "secondLevelUserId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "secondLevelUser"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      affKey: 1,
      first: 1,
      secondLevelUser: {$arrayElemAt: ["$secondLevelUser", 0]}
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "affilites",
      localField: "secondLevelUser.affKey",
      foreignField: "affKey",
      as: "secondLevelUser"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      affKey: 1,
      first: 1,
      second: {$arrayElemAt: ["$secondLevelUser.affUsers", 0]}
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      "path": "$second",
      "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: {$first: "$name"},
      affKey: {$first: "$affKey"},
      first: {$first: "$first"},
      second: {$addToSet: "$second"}
    }
  }
]);
```

After execute the query you will get result like bellow

first document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1b9df7bfdbfef2d4f1e9f3"),
    "name" : "name 1",
    "affKey" : "H1g-CfFxG",
    "first" : [ 
        ObjectId("5a1bce5e9a2918f71a9ac4fb")
    ],
    "second" : [ 
        ObjectId("5a1b9e43bfdbfef2d4f1e911"), 
        ObjectId("5a1b9e43bfdbfef2d4f1e9f8")
    ]
}
```

second document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1bce5e9a2918f71a9ac4fb"),
    "name" : "name 2",
    "affKey" : "K1gKJfFxG",
    "first" : [ 
        ObjectId("5a1b9e43bfdbfef2d4f1e9f8"), 
        ObjectId("5a1b9e43bfdbfef2d4f1e911")
    ],
    "second" : []
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I am getting results in a different order https://pastebin.com/qe6yX7bM

Comment: have you checked in mongodb ? @niksmac

Comment: Yes, I did in Robo 3T

Comment: I have tested using your data and result shown in my answer for first document and second document ....  @niksmac

Comment: here is my live data https://gist.github.com/niksmac/ba6331168a2b7aa8f8d1a0eb429cae21

Comment: so actually what you want ? I have implemented for each `user` show `first` and `second` affiliates. if *first* affiliates not present shown `null` and if *second* affiliates not present then shown **empty array**. added result in your git check pleas @niksmac

Comment: order can be change but data should be same @niksmac

Comment: As you can see, my Robo 3T giving me different results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159973/discussion-between-niksmac-and-shaishab-roy).