# How to get percentage from one collection field and one collection populated field in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have collection where one field is with number and populated ObjectId inside that collection where is one more field with number. That look like this:

> {"_id":"5abe65e298002b2334bb1470","electoralUnit":"5ab906612f30fe23dc592591","turnoutByHour":"08:00","voterTurnout":10,"safeVoter":5,"__v":0}
>
> {"_id":"5ab906612f30fe23dc592591","town":"5ab903952e9dc70408a81e32","name":"Something","__v":0,"electoralNumber":4200,"safeVoter":360}

My route look like this:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  VoterTurnout.find({})
    .sort({turnoutByHour: 1})
    .populate('electoralUnit')
    .then(voterTurnouts => {
      ElectoralUnit.find({})
        .then(electoralUnits => {
                res.render('home/voterTurnouts/index', {
                  voterTurnouts: voterTurnouts,
                  electoralUnits: electoralUnits
              });
        });
    });
});
```

View:

```
<tbody>
  {{#each voterTurnouts}}
    <tr data-row="{{electoralUnit.id}}">
      <th scope="row">{{turnoutByHour}}</th>
      <td>{{voterTurnout}} ({{Math.floor(voterTurnout * 100 / electoralUnit.electoralNumber)}}%)</td> // This doesn't working
      <td>{{safeVoter}}</td>
      <td><a href="/voterTurnouts/edit/{{id}}" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm">Izmeni</a></td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

I read something about mongodb aggregation but can't find some example that will help me with this... Any help?

Comment: You want the percentage to be displayed in the mongodb or in your table?

Comment: I need in table.

Comment: What are you using to plot the tables? How are you doing that?
I think you should just calculate the percentage on the UI at runtime

Comment: Sorry, I edit the text after you read it. There I already have numbers from voterturnouts collection but no from electoralnumbers. I presume that I need to do the math in route and then just to put variable in view.

Comment: Don't do it on the route. You will need to process all of the documents.
Just do it on the UI (HTML/js). As we don't know how you are populating the table, we cannot say how you can do it there.

Do you want to know how you can do it in the route?

Comment: You might need an agregation where you [look up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621928/how-do-i-query-referenced-objects-in-mongodb/45997377#45997377) the values from the other collection. Note that this approach requires Mongo 3.4.4 at least

Comment: Mongo version is 3.6.3 and I already populate electoralUnit (I edited first question so you can see it) successfully and get that into table. I presume that I need to populate electoralNumber in the same way?

Comment: I changed the question because I changed collections schema. Maybe the question is now more logic and clear.

Answer (score 0):

I done it with handlebars custom helper. I google [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mpetrovich/wMmHS/) handlebars custom helper and a bit edit it:

```
math: function(lvalue, operator, rvalue, options) {

    lvalue = parseFloat(lvalue);
    rvalue = parseFloat(rvalue);

    return {
        "+": lvalue + rvalue,
        "-": lvalue - rvalue,
        "*": lvalue * rvalue,
        "/": lvalue / rvalue,
        "%": Math.floor((lvalue / rvalue) * 100)
    }[operator];

}
```

then export math value to view and add this handlebars:

> {{math voterTurnout "%" electoralUnit.electoralNumber}}%

and it's working.