# MongoDB $lookup multiple localFields from one document

Tags: mongodb

I've got Adresses model:

```js
{
    user1: ObjectId(),
    user2: ObjectId()
}
```

Each user field is reference to User model. 
Is it possible to perform one lookup which will propagate data?

Comment: If you need to "join" data from an other collection via its ObjectId you might want to have a look into [an answer I gave on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621928/how-do-i-query-referenced-objects-in-mongodb/45997377#45997377)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put multiple references as following:

```
collection.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
           from: "whereyouwant",
           localField: "localfield",
           foreignField: "foreignfield",
           as: "name1"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
           from: "whereyouwant2",
           localField: "localfield2",
           foreignField: "foreignfield2",
           as: "name2"
        }
    },... rest of code
```