# How to filter documents by two combined fields and referenced field in mongoose/mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have models of `Person` and `Language`:

```
const PersonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    photo: {
        type: String,
        default: "",
        trim: true
    },
    firstName: { 
        type : String, 
        default : '', 
        trim : true 
    },
    languagePairs: [{
        source: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Language'
        } ,
        target: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Language'
        }
    }],
    status: { 
        type : String, 
        default : '', 
        trim : true 
    },
    surname: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim : true 
    }
})

const LanguageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    lang: { 
        type : String, 
        default : '', 
        trim : true 
    },
    icon: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    symbol:{
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    }
})
```

How can I filter `persons` by two combined fileds `fullName = firstName + surname`? And the second question is how can I filter by `languagePairs.source`field if I get filter as `symbol` but not as `_id`?

For the first problem I tried to use `$or` operator, but it doesn't work as expected. If `firstName = "John"` and `surname = "Black"` the filter `John Black` won't work with `$or`.

About the second question - the only solution I found by this moment is to find a `language` by `symbol` first and then use it's `_id` as a filter:

```
const language = await Language.findOne({symbol});
const persons = await Person.find({'languagePairs.source': language.id})
    .populate('languagePairs.source')
    .populate('languagePairs.target')
```

I would like to find a solution which will allow to use those filters in one single query. Is that possible and what is the best way to implement that?

Comment: why are you not taking advantage of mongodb text search index here for first question?

Comment: [useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621928/how-do-i-query-referenced-objects-in-mongodb)

Comment: I used `$text` search but it also returns all docs that contains any part of the search text in either `firstName` or `surname`. So if I search for `John Black` it will return `John Wood` and `Mike Black`.