# Finding a document in a collection whose field is an objectId but refers to another collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have these two collections defined as follows

```
let BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Object.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "author"
    }
})

let BookModel = mongoose.model("Books", BookSchema)
```

and another schema

```
let AuthorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
})

let AuthorModel = mongoose.model("author", AuthorSchema)
```

I want to search the BookModel using a query to find any Book where the title of the book or the name of the author (NOTE: not author ID but name ) includes the query.

I have defined the following code

```
let query = "";

BooksModel.find({title: {$regex: query, $options:'i'}})
```

This searches for the title, how do i also make it search that the name of the artist whose id is in the BooksModel includes the query ?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to get more information alongside the id of the referenced model. Is that correct?

Comment: I want to search the book model if the query matches the name of the artist whose id is in the book model. do you understand ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621928/how-do-i-query-referenced-objects-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in a single query using MongoDB, you'll need to have two separate queries.

```js
const queryRegexFilter = {
  $regex: query,
  $options: 'i'
};

const authors = await AuthorModel.find({
  name: queryRegexFilter
}).select('_id');

const authorsIds = authors.map(author => author._id);

const books = await BookModel.find({
  $or: [
    { title: queryRegexFilter },
    { authorId: { $in: authorsIds } }
  ]
});

doStuffWithBooks(books);
```