# $lookup on an array of objects matching by id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So I have two collections, `stock` and `store`.

I'm trying to query the store by id.

my stock looks like this

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('5ee93b1e9f96dd1257885748')
  productId: 100,
  inStore: [
    {
      _id: ObjectId('5ee7ad659f96dd1257885742'),
      store: ObjectId('5ee906e59f96dd1257885745'),
      quantity: 10
    },
    {
      _id: ObjectId('5ee9085f9f96dd1257885746'),
      store: ObjectId('5ee904549f96dd1257885744'),
      quantity: 50
    }
  ]
}
```

With `store` being a referenced object to a store

```
store: { type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Store' },
```

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('5ee904549f96dd1257885744')
  name: 'Manchester Store'
}
```

What's the correct way to query by all stock documents, that contain inStore.store._id?

I'm currently trying this (following [How do I query referenced objects in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621928/how-do-i-query-referenced-objects-in-mongodb)):

```
const inventories = await InventoryModel()
    .aggregate([  
      { $unwind: "$inStore" },
      { $lookup: {
        from: "Store",
        localField: "inStore.store",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "inStore.store"
      }},
      {$match: {
        "inStore.store._id": '5ee906e59f96dd1257885745'
      }}
    ])
```

But I'm not getting any results? but I do notice that store is an empty array, when i remove the match condition.  How do I properly use lookup in this scenario?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have the store id, you don't need to use the aggregation pipeline at all. Use  a simple find with condition

```
'inStore._id' => ObjectId('...')
```

2. Your query condition uses a string, but your ids are ObjectIds. These are different values because their types are different and therefore you won't get any matches.