# Aggregate between referenced collections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Couldn't find an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621928/how-do-i-query-referenced-objects-in-mongodb)

I got a collection of `segments`, where an example segment looks like this:

```
{
  _id: {
  $oid: "62e5778e34362ad54db6b3f9"
  },
  name: "Good-Natured Developers"
}
```

And a collection of `users`, where an example user looks like this:

```
{
   _id: {
  $oid: "62e5225dfdc41ba4f7effefa"
},
  age: {
  $numberInt: "43"
},
   segment_ids: [
 {
   $oid: "62e577a034362ad54db6b40a"
 },
 {
   $oid: "62e5782f34362ad54db6b497"
 },
 ]
}
```

How can I query how many users are there in every segment?
I tried this aggregation:

```
const usersInSegment = await userCollection
  .aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$users'},
    { $project: { "_id": 1} }, 
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'segments',
        localField: 'segment_ids',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'joined'
      }
    }
  ])
  .limit(25)
  .toArray()
```

But I get an empty array.

Comment: You don't need segments collection for that, just unwind users and group by segment.

Comment: @AlexBlex ... unless the OP needs zero counts too.

Comment: @AlexBlex I've updated the thread with a query I tried and didn't work. can u take a look?

Comment: why do you unwind users field on users collection? There is no such field and will result in empty record. Also, your project is keeping _id only which will guarantee your later lookup looking up nothing. The lookup localField and foreignField are incorrect too. Seriously, you should use some tools with ability to debug your pipeline stage by stage before posting it up here.

Comment: @ray aren't we here to help? I have an issue understanding this whole pipeline and this place is normally where you can ask

Comment: Yes. Stackoverflow helps people by **sharing knowledge** and **enabling them to learn**. That's why I point out the unusual things in your current attempt and give you a future direction by using a debugging tool to examine the pipeline stage by stage. It seems that you are not familiar with the basics of aggregation, which is perfectly fine as we are all once new users. But please take this chance to learn some basics first before posting all your things and ask someone to debug for you.